# Как правильно проектировать структуру классов в ООП (Java)?

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Пишем приложение для приемки различной номенклатуры (оборудования) от поставщиков (мониторы, принтеры и др. оргтехника). Приемка осуществляется на основании документа, в котором есть N-ое кол-во строк. Каждая строка это отдельная номенклатура с указанием наименования, кода, цены, кол-во и тд. За каждой еденицей номенклатуры закреплен один инвентарный номер. Сейчас для описания этого мы используем следующие классы:

```
// Этот класс описывает документ
class Doc {
   String docNum;  // Номер документа
   List<DocRow> rows;  // Строки документа
}

// Этот класс описывает строку документа
class DocRow {
   Nomen nomen; // Номенклатура
   int count; // Кол-во по документу
   int price; // Цена по документу
   List<Invent> invents; // Список инвентарных номеров 
}

// Этот класс описывает номенклатуру
class Nomen {
   String code; // Код
   String name; // Наименование
}

// Этот класс описывает инвентарный номер
class Invent {
  Nomen nomen; // Номенклатура
  String barcode; // Генерируемый штрих-код
}
```

В итоге вложенность классов такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что класс Nomen есть на нескольких уровнях и как-бы протаскивается ниже. Вопрос в том на сколько правильно так делать? Каковы основные правила?

Мы сделали так, потому что копии ссылок на экземпляр класса **Nomen** на разных уровнях бывают очень удобными. Например у нас есть метод для печати на принтере пачки инвентарных номеров `print(List<Invent> invents)`. Печатая инвентарный номер **Invent.barcode** требуется выводить так же и наименование. Благодаря доступу к **Invent.Nomen.name** мы можем сделать это без особых проблем, без добавления дополнительной логики по поиску этого наименования.

Класс Invent как-бы может сообщить свой штрих-код и тип номенклатуры что делает его достаточно самодостаточным. Более того, в будущем мы можем использовать класс **Invent** вообще вне класса **DocRow** и тогда уж точно нужно понимать к какому типу номенклатуры принадлежит данные инвентарный номер.

Что подскажут коллеги с многолетним опытом?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не имею многолетнего опыта, но почему не хотите метод print опустить на уровень класса Invent? И использовать так:

```
class DocRow {
...
  void print() {
    foreach(Invent invent : invents) {
      invent.print();
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Даже если вызывать метод print() у объекта Invent, он все равно должен содержать в себе объект Nomen что бы печатать всю нужную информацию, поэтому где он будет находиться сейчас не столь важно. Суть вопроса в том на сколько правильно плодить ссылки на объект Nomen.

Comment: @UltimateOrb Хорошей практикой программирования является низкая связность системы. Чем больше классов будет завязано на Nomen или какой-то другой, тем больше будет "связность" системы, и тем сложнее будет ее модифицировать. В моем примере поле Nomen уже не нужно в классе в классе DocRow, соответственно класс Nomen будет связан только с классом Invent.

Comment: Это все хорошо. Но в какой-то момент времени у нас появляется задача что бы на форме просто вывести строки документа в виде: наименование номенклатуры -> кол-во -> цена. И тут-то было бы удобно просто пробежать DocRow взять count, price, nomen.name.

Comment: Кажется понял вашу сложность. Уточню: (1) может-ли count в классе DocRow отличаться от кол-ва в List<Invent>? (2) price в DocRow - это суммарная цена всех Invent-ов в этом листе? (3) Если "2" - да, то можно-ли в сущность invent добавить поле price и является-ли она одинаковой для всех invent-ов с одинаковой номентклатурой?

Comment: Пихать print  в DocRow точно плохо. Ведь DocRow - это просто данные, а тут с бухты барахты логика печати. А если мы захотим чуть чуть по разному печатать для каждого случая? А если мы захотим вообще выводить как JSON в api и отправлять по сети? Плюс это увеличивает связности во много раз больше чем просто дублирующийся Nomen. Да и дублировать Nomen некрасиво. Имхо print(List<invent> invents, Nomen nomen) выглядит получше.

Comment: А вообще совет. То, что вы сейчас разрабатываете это не архитектура. Это скорее просто модель данных. Проектировать лучше начинать с функций и интерфейсов. Подумайте, какой функционал у вас будет, что он будет делать, что ему нужно знать для этих действий, а что будет точно лишним.

Comment: Вариант с print(List<invent> invents, Nomen nomen) тоже плох. Я могу пустить на печать инветарные номера не только одной номенклатуры, а сразу всех что есть в документе. Тогда мне придется сначала раскидать по пасивам объект invent с одним типо номенклатуры и тогда уже в цикле вызывать print. Больше лишней логики в программе.

Comment: Пусть не архитектура, пусть модель данных. Но вопрос все равно открыт. На сколько моя модель данных правильная.